# How to find matching 'StartsWith' documents on classless MongoDB using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents:

```
{"handler":"north"}
{"handler":"south"}
{"handler":"west"}
{"handler":"east"}
```

I want to find a matching handler from a given string input, e.g. `"westtown"` and expects the handler will be `"west"`.

Please help, my code below does not work.

```
String inputstring = "westtown";
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = null;
List<BsonDocument> pages = null;

try
{
     collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("handlers");
     pages = await collection.Find(x => (inputstring.StartsWith(x["handler"].AsString))).ToListAsync<BsonDocument>();
}
...
```

I use classless scheme, so I use `BsonDocument` on the dynamic.

Comment: If you want the search term "westtown" to match with a document with the handler field "west" you will need to look into some sort of fuzzy matching for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, In MongoDB you can find it with `$where` operator like this:

```
{  $where: "'westtown'.startsWith(this.handler)" }
```

So, I think in c# you can do it with something like this:

```
var filter =
    new BsonDocument(
        new Dictionary<string, BsonValue>
            {
                {
                    "$where",
                    new BsonString("'westtown'.startsWith(this.handler)")
                }
            });
var result = col.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes. It is working. I thought the $where does not work on that way in the first place. Thank you very much ^_^